# Getting null value in attempt to read Claims from Identity

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, claims-based-identity, .net-core-2.0

I am working on a .NET Core application, Web Api and integrate Azure B2C authentication. Now I need to read claims and for some reason I am getting null even tho I can see values in stack expect identity Object value is working, not sure what I am missing from puzzle

### This is working:

```
 var userId = identity?.Claims.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")?.Value;
```

### The following is not working and returning null:

```
var UserId = listedUserGuid;
var Email = identity?.Claims.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")?.Value;
var  Name = identity?.Claims.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
var Surname = identity?.Claims.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 you can also use the convenience method `FindFirst`:

```
User.FindFirst("email");
```

So you don't even have to worry about the identity property.

Answer (score 0):

found answer;

```
               var UserId = listedUserGuid;
               var Email = identity?.Claims.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "emails")?.Value;
               var  Name = identity?.Claims.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname")?.Value;
               var Surname = identity?.Claims.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname")?.Value;
```